# How to convert latitude longitude into CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cllocationcoordinate2d

I want to convert lat lon to `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

```
self.currentLocation = {.latitude = 0.0, .longitude = 0.0};
```

This gives me error "Expected expression".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try to cast the expression to *CLLocationCoordinate2D*. See if my answer below helps you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees latitude, CLLocationDegrees longitude)` to create the coordinates.

Answer (score 7):

While you could use `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` you have to pay attention because it is available in iOS 4.0 and later **only**. You can try this to make it 'manually':

```
CLLocationCoordinate coordinate;
coordinate.latitude = 0.0;
coordinate.longitude = 0.0;

self.currentLocation = coordinate;
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code seems to be correct. That should not throw any errors/warnings. Make sure *self.currentLocation* is a *CLLocationCoordinate2D*. Try to cast the expression like below,

```
self.currentLocation = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){.latitude = 0.0, .longitude = 0.0};
```

Alternatively you can also use *CLLocationCoordinate2DMake* method.

Answer (score 1):

**Update > Swift 4**

```
let loc_coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.601089,-52.740439)
```

For more details please have a look to apple developer website:
[CLLocationCoordinate2DMake](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/1423838-cllocationcoordinate2dmake)

Thanks